# Change Google Sheet sharing settings using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, file-sharing

I have a script that creates a number of Google sheets (by duplicating a master and then adding specific data to each sheet) when it runs and puts each sheet into a different folder. Each folder is shared with different people (editors) so different people can see each sheet.

For each sheet that is created I want to stop each editor being able to share the file with others.

I have found how to check this permission using `file.isShareableByEditors()` but I cannot see how to change it.

The master file that I am duplicating does have this setting enabled however when duplicating the permission is not carried over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy Google Spreadsheet + Share with same users in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255623/copy-google-spreadsheet-share-with-same-users-in-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [setShareableByEditors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setShareableByEditors(Boolean)) prevents file sharing by editors:

```
const stopEditorsFromSharingFile_ = file => file.setShareableByEditors(false)
```