# Is it possible to enable only print but disable download and copy for a google drive file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, urlfetch

**I tried using this code but did not work**

This code is from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63664501 written by [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653)

> ```js
> function myFunction() {
>   const fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID.
>
>   const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId;
>   const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
>     method: "patch",
>     headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
>     contentType: "application/json",
>     payload: JSON.stringify({ writersCanShare: false, copyRequiresWriterPermission: false}),
>   });
>   console.log(res.getContentText())
>   
>   // DriveApp.createFile(blob)  // This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
> }
> ```

This disables all the features including print as well.
If this is not possible can we use the google app script to print the iframe content only from a pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

The functionality built-in to Docs only allows turning off all copying (including printing) — it's not possible to only turn off copying but allow printing, for example.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to use Apps Script to access and print (or email a copy-protected PDF to) users somehow, rather than letting them access it directly.